# Android Pedometer showing incorrect steps

Tags: java, android, sensors, pedometer

I have created a simple android step counter in Java. I have the step counter working but for some reason when I boot up the application it starts off at 62000 steps. I have not hardcoded this value anywhere in my code and I am unsure of why this is showing. Below I provide a screenshot and a snippet of the code. Any ideas on this?

[what the UI looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfCeG.jpg)

```java
public class Pedometer extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {
    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private TextView count;
    private boolean running;
    private Button reset;
    private CircularProgressBar circularProgressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pedometer);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        count = findViewById(R.id.stepTextView);
        reset = findViewById(R.id.resetSteps);
        circularProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.circularBar);
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                count.setText("0");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        running = true;
        Sensor countSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
        if(countSensor != null) {
            sensorManager.registerListener(Pedometer.this,countSensor,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(Pedometer.this,"Sensor not found.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        running = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        running = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if(running) {
            int currentSteps = (int) event.values[0];
            count.setText(String.valueOf(currentSteps));
            circularProgressBar.setProgressWithAnimation(currentSteps);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }
}
```

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:padding="@dimen/box_inset_layout_padding"
    tools:context=".Pedometer"
    tools:deviceIds="wear">

<com.mikhaellopez.circularprogressbar.CircularProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/circularBar"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    app:cpb_background_progressbar_color="#FF0000"
    app:cpb_round_border="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.499" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/stepTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/circularBar" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/resetSteps"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:text="Reset Counter"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/stepTextView" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you put your xml layout file?

Comment: @JuanSancho I have added the xml layout file

Comment: The sensor return the Number of steps taken by the user since the last reboot while the sensor was activated. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion

Comment: @Christopher I am not sure I quite understand I developed this code today and ran it on a different phone for the first time

Comment: If you reboot that phone. Does the counter start at nearly zero?